# custom-speech-to-text slow on first invocation after inactivity

Tags: docker, azure-cognitive-services, speech

Upon first launch and after a period of inactivity, our custom-speech-to-text docker container takes a long time to reply (10+ seconds vs sub 1 second response times for subsequent invocations).

Here is the docker-compose lines used to run the container:

```yaml
  msasr:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-services/speechservices/custom-speech-to-text:2.6.0-amd64
    volumes:
       - ./MS_ASR_20201202:/usr/local/models
    restart: always
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '4'
          memory: 4G
        reservations:
          cpus: '4'
          memory: 4G
    command: Eula=accept Billing=${MS_ENDPOINT_URI} ApiKey=${MS_API_KEY}
```

docker-compose is run with the --compatibility flag to for the memory allocations

This problem appeared after moving to the custom-speech-to-text:2.6.0-amd64 from the cognitive-services-custom-speech-to-text:2.2.0-amd64-preview

I suppose (no proof here) that there are some elements that need to be loaded into ram and are discarded when no in use, but this has a large QOS impact later on. Is there a way to tell the instance to keep them loaded, or re-prime the system?

Answer (score 0):

This symptom suggests page-outs are occurring. In the past, the following actions have very effectively solved this:

- Use 8G to ensure that all locales have the resources they need without any risk of requiring swap space.
- Disable swap on the host entirely if permissible.
- Ensure that there are not other processes that could lead to physical memory oversubscription. In other words, ensure the sum of reservations does not exceed the physical host.

Please let me know how this goes.

Andrew

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your reply.

I've implemented all 3 suggestions, and the situation has improved somewhat.

However we are still seeing very high volatility in response times (0.4 to 20 seconds for 5/6s of speech).

Would you have any suggestions regarding stabilising these values?